# Inconsistent Votes in user profile vs. answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, profile-page, voting

The [user profile for Stack Overflow user David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56541/david) lists 229 points for his top rated answer:

```
229    Programming challenge: can you code a hello world program as a Palindrome? (3)
```

However, when you [view his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/660276#660276), it lists `+43/-1` votes.

This looks like a bug to me.  I would expect his profile to list something like +42 to his answer:

```
42    Programming challenge: can you code a hello world program as a Palindrome? (3)
```

**Update**:

[Downvoter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40953/inconsistent-votes-in-user-profile-vs-answer/40954#40954) helped me realize what's going on...  User David has three answers:

- [Brainf**k answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/660212#660212) +168/-1
- [Python answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/660276#660276) +43/-1
- [John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/659776#659776) +25/-5

So the sum of points is `167 + 42 + 20 = 229 == 229`

However, the "Answers" in his profile still links to just the Python answer.  I find this confusing & think Stack Overflow should have 3 separate answers listed in the users profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, he has 3 answers on that question.

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so8.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/so8.png)

You were missing [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/659776#659776), that has +25/-5

So... 167 + 42 + 20 = 229 == 229

Comment: +1 for use of MS Paint!  This "feature" is confusing:  It takes you to an answer with _3 comments_.  I think the user profile should contain separate links to each answer.

Comment: I couldn't live without it @pete

Comment: *ISSUE:* Answer has only two comments.  Spec requires 3. *ACTION:* Added comment. *STATUS:* Closed as Fixed.