# Answer count in profile incorrect when questions have been answered more than once

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, answer-count

In the user profile, questions on which the user has posted more than one answer [are grouped into one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2747/stop-grouping-together-multiple-answers-to-the-same-question-in-user-profile).

This leads to a wrong answer count: I, for example, don't currently have *169 answers* on Meta; instead there are *169 questions I have answered*.

[alt text http://img519.imageshack.us/img519/573/wrong.png](http://img519.imageshack.us/img519/573/wrong.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40953/inconsistent-votes-in-user-profile-vs-answer

Comment: You can see on that link, that this is `[status-bydesign]`

Comment: @Downvoter: How is *that* question even remotely a dupe?

Comment: Because it's the same question?

Comment: (it's a particular case of what you're saying, read the accepted answer)

Comment: @Downvoter: Is it possible you mistyped the number? I'm not ruling out that I've posted a dupe, but the question you linked to has nothing to do with mine -- mine is about the *Answer count*, yours is about the number of *votes* on the particular answers.

Comment: well, I see it's kinda a dupe, actually, I meant to say the answer is addressing the issue, and it's mark as bydesign. So it would be a duplicate of the answer, so you're right. I'd unvote to close.

Comment: @Downvoter: The folding of several answers into one link is by-design -- I understand that. But the number above the list (169 in my example) is not `COUNT(*) FROM Answers WHERE Owner=Me`, as the wording suggests, but instead it's `COUNT(*) FROM Question WHERE AnsweredByMe` -- which is a different number as soon as I have several answers on the same question.

Comment: you are right, I misread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, showing the *actual* total answers, rather than the number of questions answered.

Previously this total was the row total...but since answers are rolled-up before that happens, this was incorrect.

Comment: I think this change might have introduced a small bug in pagination, could you check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91258/pagination-of-answers-on-the-profile-page-wrongly-uses-the-number-of-answers-inst ?