# Strange behavior in the profile page account section

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer count in profile incorrect when questions have been answered more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45578/answer-count-in-profile-incorrect-when-questions-have-been-answered-more-than-onc)

I have given 102 answers in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296418/nikhil-jain) but when I go to my account section where I can see all my accounts, over there it's showing [103 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296418/nikhil-jain?tab=accounts). Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Updated:

Same happen for questions on meta, I have asked [2 question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156646/nikhil-jain) on meta but account page showing [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296418/nikhil-jain?tab=accounts).

Comment: Caching? Have you recently deleted an answer or noticed that one's gone missing due to question deletion?

Comment: No, recently I haven't deleted any answer.

Comment: Somebody might have deleted their question and hence it would've reduced the count in your profile

Comment: @Sachine: if so, then accounts section should also show the same figure.

Comment: @Nikhil - As ChrisF mentioned, I doubt it could be caching in Accounts section hence it still shows 103. Will get updated in some time.

Comment: @Nikhil to improve performance, I guess the accounts tab show cached data while the profile page show "real time" data - when a question with answers gets deleted they probably don't have loop that reduce 1 from the cache of all answers but I'm sure there's daily job for this. If tomorrow you'll still see the difference it's really a bug. :)

Comment: @Shadow: ok, I will wait for tomorrow, and let see what will happen :)

Comment: @YOU good catch! @Nikhil - you were correct all along, bug indeed..

Comment: @Shadow:If it is a bug then where should I report?

Comment: Nikhil -  you already reported it by posting here with "bug" tag - that's the proper way to report, and the moderators will take a look in their own time. They're not always telling when they plan to fix but many bugs are getting fixed then they change the tag to "status-completed". The other question @YOU found is also related and he bumped it so it's all good. :)

Answer (score 1):

You've answered this question two times.

[How to get a list of all html files in all subdirectories alphabetically sorted in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665318/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-html-files-in-all-subdirectories-alphabetically-sorted-i)

may be 102 answers in your profile mean that you have answered 102 questions.

but account page is probably actally counting your answers, so it is total 103 answers.

**ps**: I don't mean this shoundn't fix, but I noticed like that.

Comment: It might be the reason but I have noticed one more thing, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you give any answer to a question and later the question has been closed due to some reasons then it might considered in the account page.

I am giving this reasoning because I found that as I have asked [2 questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156646/nikhil-jain) on meta, one is closed and second is active but on account page, it showing [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296418/nikhil-jain?tab=accounts).

so may be it applies the same logic on answers too.

If it is the correct reasoning then still **it should be correct**.

Comment: you have more than 3 answers on closed questions[[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193977/id-love-to-learn-regular-expressions-what-would-you-suggest-me-to-start-off-wit/3194048#3194048),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359806/how-do-i-learn-about-programming-fundamentals/3360111#3360111),[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965497/regex-for-finding-number-of-times-substring-hello-hello-occurs-in-string-hello/3965586#3965586)], thats not related IMHO.

Comment: @YOU: Nice finding that means reason is something else.