# Pagination of answers on the profile page wrongly uses the number of answers instead of the number of answered questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, pagination

I think there is a minor bug in the pagination of answers on the user page.

You can see it on [my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322283/marijn#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_views-ansort_recent) now.

At the time of writing, I have 63 answers which results in three 30-line pages.
However, since answers to the same question are rolled up into a single "answer line" in the list, the actual number of pages should be two, since I have a couple of questions where I provided two answers and one with three.

Now I have an empty last answer page :-(

When rolling up answers to the same question into a single line, I suspect that the number of pages is calculated wrongly, because it uses the total number of answers provided. It should count the number of questions answered instead.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45578/answer-count-in-profile-incorrect-when-questions-have-been-answered-more-than-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was indeed using the wrong total here, the total *number of answers* rather than the number *of distinct questions answered* when determining the paging...which is now the case.

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: confirmed; pagination is OK now - 62 answers, resulting in 2 pages